# What is the cons of using unity built in network manager?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, online-game

Why do Unity game developers implement server by themselves instead of using unity built-in `NetworkManager`?

It seems like multi online games can easily be developed by using `NetworkManager`,
but why do developers implement server by themselves using node.js, ... etc??

Comment: I don't know a crazy amount amount about Unities network manager, but if I were to assume it would probably be the peer portion of the game. Unless the game is peer to peer, instead of client to server, you'd still need to build a server for it.

Answer (score 1):

Its my understanding that it is not possible for two *separate* unity projects to talk to each other using the Unity `HLAPI` (High Level API, which is what `NetworkManager` is utilizing).

That  means that you would have to have all the server code, and all the client code, in the same project. 
This doesnt have to be a problem really, but for larger scale projects, separating the server from client can be easier to work with, and you dont push out all the server code to the clients to possibly reverse engineer.

Lets say you have a round-based, non-realtime game like scrabble, in this case it would make sense to use node or any `http` protocol, where you have a centralized server with a database for persisting game states.

But i honestly have no clue why anyone would prefer pure sockets when you have the Unity `TLAPI` (Transport Layer API)

> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html

I hope this was somewhat helpful and not just a rant.